# How to add drop down change event in kendo foreign key bound column inside kendo grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a foregin key bound column in Kendo grid, I have to add change event on the kendo dropdown , so that i can populate others nested dropdown inside kendo grid.

columns.ForeignKey(c => c.City)

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you looked into [Cascading Dropdowns](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist)? I haven't tried it in a grid before, but it might be possible.

Comment: Here's documentation to [Add Cascading DropDownList Editors](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors#add-cascading-dropdownlist-editors) to your grid.